# Quiero pasar de un form a otro con un evento ONCLICK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Lo que ocurre es que el programa que estoy manejando tiene un form principal Form1 el cual no se cierra nunca. Tengo un menu a la izquierda con botones que abren forms en un panel a traves del siguiente metodo:

```
private void AbrirFormEnPanel(object Formhijo)
{
    if (this.panelContenedor.Controls.Count > 0)
     this.panelContenedor.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    Form fh = Formhijo as Form;
    fh.TopLevel = false;
      fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     this.panelContenedor.Controls.Add(fh);
     this.panelContenedor.Tag = fh;
     fh.Show();
         }
```

El cual hace que se abra el nuevo form en el panel la cuestion es que tengo un datagrid en un form el cual quiero obtener un dato de el a traves de un evento dobleclick y con ese dato irme a otro form el cual obtenga ese dato. Seria con herencia entre las forms? Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: A ver si entiendo. Usted quiere que cuando abra un form X que tiene un datagrid, al darle click a un boton en ese form X  se abra un form Y y a ese form Y pasarle un dato del datagrid del form X ??????

Comment: Exacto pero sin salir del form1 ya que el form x se abre en un panel del form1. Lo que quiero es que al darle click a un boton en ese form x se abra el form Y desde el mismo panel del form1 sin abrir una ventana nueva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograrlo definiendo un evento al form `Formhijo`. En tu caso, puedes lograrlo utilizando una interfaz:

1 - Define una interfaz que tendra evento:

```
public interface IFormEvent
{
  event EventHandler<int> OnFormEvent;
}
```

2- Luego que implementes la interfaz, ejecutas el evento donde lo vayas a necesitar:

```
public class FormHijo : Form, IFormEvent // implementamos la interfaz
{
  public event EventHandler<int> OnFormEvent;

  void DatosGuardados()
  {
    OnFormEvent(333); // le enviamos 333 como parametro a los metodos suscritos
  }
}
```

En tu caso, lo ejecutaras donde necesites.

3 - Entonces cuando agregues el form, te suscribes al evento:

```
private void AbrirFormEnPanel(object Formhijo)
{
    if (this.panelContenedor.Controls.Count > 0)

     this.panelContenedor.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    Form fh = Formhijo as Form;


    // Verificamos que el formulario implemente la interfaz
    if(fh is IFormEvent)
    {
        // obtenemos la referencia del evento para suscribirnos
        ((IFormEvent)fh).OnFormEvent = (_sender, numero) => {
          MessageBox.Show($"La data enviada fue {numero}");
        };
    }

    fh.TopLevel = false;
    fh.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.panelContenedor.Controls.Add(fh);
    this.panelContenedor.Tag = fh;
    fh.Show();
}
```

Y listo. Cuando el formulario ejecute el evento OnFormEvent, se ejecutara el evento tambien en el formulario principal.

Answer (score 0):

Ok vamos a suponer que el form X es el Form1 y el form Y el Form2.
Lo que hay que hacer es en el Form2 sobrecargar el constructor y pasarle por parametro una variable de tipo Form1.
De esta forma:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 F;


        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Form2(Form1 f1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            F = f1;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(F.Prop);
        }
    }
```

Y en el Form1 simplemente se crea una instancia de el Form 2 pero usando el constructor sobrecargado y para poder pasar el valor de un form a otro yo lo que hice fue declarar una propiedad pública y en un evento de botón pasarle el valor del datagrid a la propiedad , aunque podría pasarse directamente desde el datagrid pero para eso tiene que modificar el datagrid y ponerlo como público para que pueda ser accesible desde Form2 :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string Prop { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("dato defecto");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Prop = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            new Form2(this).Show();
        }
    }
```